# C++11 Watchdog class, test application doesn't want to exit

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, watchdog

I am using an online `C++11` compiler, link found here: [cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/) (C++ Shell).

In my current project, I would like to have a watchdog class, to be able to check somehow the status of a thread or FSM (for example).

After some work (I'm not a `C++11` guru), I finally got the code below, that compiles ok.
 I also did some basic/trivial tests, but it seems **the test program doesn't want to exit**.
It says "*Program running*" and the only way to (force) exit is to hit the "*Stop*" button... :(

Well, my *question* : **What am I doing wrong?**
Any ideas, suggestions you can provide are highly appreciated.

Here is the `full code`, including my test app:

> **Watchdog (as MCVE):**

```
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::chrono;

class Watchdog
{
public:
    Watchdog();
    ~Watchdog();
    void Start(unsigned int milliseconds, std::function<void()> callback = 0);
    void Stop();
    void Pet();

private:
    unsigned int m_interval;
    std::atomic<bool> m_running;
    std::thread m_thread;
    std::function<void()> m_callback;
    std::mutex m_mutex;
    steady_clock::time_point m_lastPetTime;
    std::condition_variable m_stopCondition;
    void Loop();
}; 

Watchdog::Watchdog()
{
    m_running = false;
}

Watchdog::~Watchdog()
{
    Stop();
}

void Watchdog::Start(unsigned int milliseconds, std::function<void()> callback)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(m_mutex);
    if(m_running == false)
    {
        m_lastPetTime = steady_clock::now();
        m_interval = milliseconds;
        m_callback = callback;
        m_running = true;
        m_thread = std::thread(&Watchdog::Loop, this);
    }
}

void Watchdog::Stop()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(m_mutex);
    if(m_running == true)
    {
        m_running = false;
        m_stopCondition.notify_all();
        m_thread.join();
    }
}

void Watchdog::Pet()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(m_mutex);
    m_lastPetTime = steady_clock::now();
    m_stopCondition.notify_all();
}

void Watchdog::Loop()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(m_mutex);
    while(m_running == true)
    {
        if(m_stopCondition.wait_for(locker, milliseconds(m_interval)) == std::cv_status::timeout)
        {
            if(m_callback != nullptr)
                m_callback();
        }
    }
}  

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Watchdog wdog;

    wdog.Start(3000, [] { std::cout << " WDOG TRIGGERED!!! "; });
    for(auto i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "[+]";
        wdog.Pet();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
    }
}
```

-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing a deadlock here.

```
void Watchdog::Stop()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(m_mutex);
    if(m_running == true)
    {
        m_running = false;
        m_stopCondition.notify_all();
        m_thread.join();
        ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
          m_mutex is locked; m_thread cannot continue execution
    }
}
```

Some additional suggestion: use simple `if` conditions, do not compare with `true` or `false`.

Comment: _Question_: What's the reason one should avoid comparison with `true/false`? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @groenhen simply because they're hard to read. it also saves some characters ;)

Comment: So, the idea is to just unlock `m_mutex` right **before** `join()`, correct?

Comment: Yes. (There's no problem to unlock it before notifying though, since you're using condvar correctly.)

Comment: A lil'bit off-topic: Regarding `true/false` comparison: For me it's easier to read `if(running == false)` than `if(!running)`, simply because if you don't have eagle eyes than in 90% cases you'll definitely miss the `!` sign, sometimes with catastrophic consequences, hehe... ;) _Upvoted, thanx!_

Comment: **Out of curiosity**: In order to detect the above mutex issue, did you use a tool to perform some sort of _static/dynamic_ `code checking`?

Comment: No, just in brain analysis, I didn't even run the code. Helgrind is a tool to detect some deadlock and data race, if you wanted to give a try.